# LCD isn't working with if statement

Tags: programming, lcd

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
#define trigpinyellow 10
#define echopingreen 9
#define Grove_Water_Sensor 8
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(trigpinyellow,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echopingreen,INPUT);
    pinMode(Grove_Water_Sensor, INPUT);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() 
{
    long duration,distance;
    digitalWrite(trigpinyellow,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
    digitalWrite(trigpinyellow,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
    digitalWrite(trigpinyellow,LOW);
    duration=pulseIn(echopingreen,HIGH);
    distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
    Serial.println(distance);

    if( digitalRead(Grove_Water_Sensor) == LOW && digitalRead(distance) >=20  )
    {
        lcd.clear();  
        lcd.print("water_came");  
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    }
    if( digitalRead(Grove_Water_Sensor) == LOW && digitalRead(distance) <=8 )
    {
        lcd.clear();  
        lcd.write("Tank_is_full");
    }
    if( digitalRead(Grove_Water_Sensor) == HIGH && digitalRead(distance) >=20 )
    {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Fill The Tank PLEASE");  
    }
    if( digitalRead(Grove_Water_Sensor) == HIGH && digitalRead(distance) <=8 )
    {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Tank_is_FULL");  
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to change `digitalRead(distance) >=20` to just `distance >=20`

Comment: Your collection of if statements has holes which could result in no output to the lcd. For example, if Grove_Water_Sensor is LOW and distance is 10 would result in no output.

Comment: I will try it Gerben, 6v6gt and thanks for the advice

Comment: But why it will not show any output

Comment: Voted down. Please add more content, what is not working?

Comment: @Omar: you read some distance to variable `distance`. So this variable now contain some more/less random `long` number. Then you call `digitalRead(distance)` where you read pin with this number - so you read some random (maybe even non-existent) pin. With `digitalRead` you read digital, so result is else `HIGH` or `LOW` (which are 1 or 0). And then you compare valoue of 1 or 0 (obtained from random pin) with values like 8 or 20. Do you see, why it does not work this way?

Comment: Okay my problem is that When it is<=8 it gives tank is full but when it becomes >=20 after the lcd remains tank is full so the lcd display isn't changing at all so please help me

Comment: @Omar - the "answer" area is not for clarifying your question or replying to comments. This is not a forum. If you are asked a question in a comment, make a comment to reply. If you need to clarify your question edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you instantiate digitalread(), you poll the pin. Here, you're polling pins 8 times every loop. Instead, poll the two pins at the start of the loop to update the variable, and then do your math and make your decisions afterward. Right now you're doing math with your distance variable, and then overwriting the variable during your if conditionals. Not sure if that's what you intend. You're also creating the variables duration and distance every single loop. instead, create those variables globally and just update them every loop.